# Output: File Not Available if it doesn't match the pattern

Tags: php, file, foreach, scandir

Here is the Code:

```
        $course = htmlspecialchars($_GET["course"]);
        $db = odbc_connect('#');

        // Course Heading
        $courseheading = "SELECT * 
        FROM tbsessions, tbcourses, tbpresentations 
        WHERE (tbsessions.courseId = tbcourses.courseId) 
        AND (tbpresentations.courseSessionId = tbsessions.courseSessionId) 
        AND (tbsessions.courseSessionID = '$course') 
        AND (tbsessions.category NOT IN ('M','S')) 
        ORDER BY startDate DESC, courseTitle";

        $courseRS = odbc_exec($db, $courseheading);
        $courseTitle = odbc_result($courseRS, "courseTitle");
        $subtitle = odbc_result($courseRS, "subtitle");

            echo '<div class="title">
                <h1>'.$courseTitle.'</h1>
            <p>'.$subtitle.'</p></div>';

        // Presentation Information
        $query = "SELECT *
        FROM tbspeakers s join tbpresentations p on
        s.spkrId = p.spkrId

        join tbsessions ss on
        p.courseSessionid = ss.courseSessionId

        join tbcourses c on
        ss.courseId = c.courseId

        WHERE (ss.courseSessionID = '$course')

        ORDER BY pTitle";


        $result = odbc_exec($db, $query);
    // Generate presentation and speaker information    
        while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
                $courseTitle = odbc_result($result, "courseTitle");
                $subtitle = odbc_result($result, "subtitle");
                $pTitle = odbc_result($result, "pTitle");
                $fname = odbc_result($result, "fname");
                $lname = odbc_result($result, "lname");
                $degree = odbc_result($result, "degree");
                $pSDateTime = odbc_result($result, "pSDateTime");


                echo '<p><strong>'.$pTitle. '</strong> - ' . $fname . ' ' . $lname . ', ' . $degree . '</p>';
                $courseTitle = explode(" ", $courseTitle);
                $course = "";
                $courseTitle = preg_replace('/\(|\)/', '', $courseTitle);
                foreach ($courseTitle as $value) {
                    $course .= substr($value, 0, 2);
                }
                $pSDateTime = str_replace('-', '', $pSDateTime);
                $pSDateTime = str_replace(':', '', $pSDateTime);
                $pSDateTime = str_replace(' ', '_', $pSDateTime);
                $pSDateTime = substr($pSDateTime, 0, -2);
                $presentation = strToLower($course). '_' .$pSDateTime;

            // Generate presentation download link
                $dir    = '../assets/training/archive';
                $files = scandir($dir);
                $imgarray = array();
                foreach($files as $file) {
                  if(fnmatch($presentation.'.*',$file)) {
                    $imgarray[] = $file;
                  }
                }

                foreach($imgarray as $download) {
                  if(isset($download)) {
                      echo '<p><a href="/assets/training/archive/'.$download.'">Download</a></p> <br><br>';
                  }
                  else {
                      echo 'File Not Available';
                  }
                }


        }
    ?>
```

Task:
I'm trying to only grab files that match the file that matches the presentation.  All other files should not be considered, that way if it doesn't find a match it will show "File Not Available".

Comment: Why would the `scandir` readout contain a file that doesn't exist?

Comment: .. and here is a list of random files we DONT have ..

Comment: One question, user4771351 : if the folder has 50 files, and only 10 match the pattern, do you want to display 10 links and 40 File not available? Is that so?

Comment: Jose my intention is to only display "File Not Available" once if it doesn't find the specific file.  If it finds 10 then it should output 10 if it doesn't find anything, it should output "File Not Available" once.

Comment: Well, what you need looks like my deleted answer. I think I'm gonna undelete it for you to take a look at it. Rizier kicked my butt yesterday for my answer, but maybe it can be useful for you, user4771351.

Comment: I insist you only need one IF before the second FOREACH, and remove the IF inside the FOREACH.

Comment: Jose your code did work!  `if ( count( $imgarray ) == 0 )` I completely overlooked the `$imgarray[] = $file;` when it looks for the match.

Comment: Great! It's good to see code running. Now, it's time to accept and answer (and upvote it!).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add one IF to know if array is empty or not :

```
<html>
  <body>
<?php
$dir = "../assets/training/archive";
$files = scandir($dir);
$imgarray = array();
$presentation = '*.php'; // ENTER ANY FILENAME OR PATTERN HERE.
foreach($files as $file)
  if(fnmatch($presentation,$file))
     $imgarray[] = $file;

if ( count( $imgarray ) == 0 ) // NO MATCHES.
     echo 'No files available';
else foreach($imgarray as $download)
       echo '<p><a href="/assets/training/archive/'.$download.'">Download</a></p> <br><br>';
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: `if(isset($download))` This is just completely redundant, and with the current code from OP shown his code makes no sense

Comment: Maybe he is trying to know if the file data was properly retrieved or not, in such case the array position would be null.

Comment: Makes no difference it's just completely non sense! Pseudo code: `(foreach $array as $element) if (current element of the loop isset) then else then` <- Maybe this helps you to understand it

Comment: (foreach $array as $element) if (current element of the loop isset) then DISPLAY IT else NOT AVAILABLE.

Comment: ^ You don't get it right? If you loop through the array each element is set otherwise it wouldn't be in the array?!

Comment: Ok, I get it, Rizier. Anyway, the question was how to display that no files where found matching the pattern.

Comment: OP wanted to show `No files available` if the current file of the loop didn't matched the pattern of `fnmatch()`! (Maybe if you look at my answer you see it, also edited OP's Q to make it more clear for further readers)

Comment: You and I have a different interpretation of the question. Maybe you are right.

Comment: NO! You just have to read the edited question, OR if you read the [original one](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29550048/1) multiple times you will see: `I don't know how to show File Not Available if a file` **does not match** <- This is based on the `fnmatch()` function if it matches the *pattern*, which is an argument of the function, or not

Comment: Rizier, you have convinced me.

Comment: The `if ( count( $imgarray ) == 0 )` statement is what worked with my code.  I overlooked the fnmatch that is saved into the `$imgarray[]`  Thank you all for your input.

Comment: @user4771351 Wow are you for real? If this is what you wanted; Then your question is very unclear!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Here I first get all files from your directory with [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) which already exclude `.` and `..`. Then I filter all files out which doesn't match the pattern with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). At the end I simply loop through all files and I check with [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) if the current file matched the pattern and is in the filtered array or no.

```
<?php

    $dir = "../assets/training/archive";
    $files = glob("$dir/*.*");

    $filteredFiles = array_filter($files, function($v)use($presentation){
        return fnmatch($presentation.'.*', $v);
    });

    foreach($files as $file) {
        if(in_array($file, $filteredFiles)) 
            echo "<p><a href='/assets/training/archive/'". $file . "'>Download</a></p><br><br>";
        else
            echo "File Not Available";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74960/discussion-on-answer-by-rizier123-output-file-not-available-if-it-doesnt-match).